# Most efficient way to do with contacts

Tags: android, sqlite

I'd like to get all contacts from my phone. From GSM card and from phone memory too. All contacts with names, surnames, phone numbers, nicks, emails and a dew more maybe. I wonder what would be the fastest and the most efficient way to do that. My Android version id 2.2.somethig but solution should support all version above 2.1.

Any suggestions?

// BTW. Maybe you could give me some good tutorial to doing with Android contacts db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to query the contacts provider. Depending on what data you need, you would also need to adjust the query and set up some filtering.

Querying [`ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_URI) will get you all contact entries from the provider.

For being efficient it depends on how you deal with the data returned by the provider. To reduce the workload it is crucial to only request that data you really need. For example, if you care only about contacts with a phone number you can add the following to the selection parameter:

```
ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = '" ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'"
```

Take a look at [`CursorLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html), which takes care to not block the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for post. It seems helpful : )

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html
check this one out, it helped me with an assignment.

Comment: It looks good for the first look. I'm going to read this, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Get htc sync, and connect your phone with your charger cable.  There you can see all the info on your android.

http://www.htc.com/www/software/htc-sync-manager/download/

only availible on windows

Comment: Well... Sorry. I mean about do this programmatically - I want to implement this into my application.

Comment: This is not what is asked in question.